# Null Object pattern with simple class hierarchy

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism, null

I have a simple two-class hierarchy to represent U.S. ZIP (12345) and ZIP+4 (12345-1234) codes. To allow clients to allow both types for a field/parameter or restrict it to one type or the other, the specific types inherit from a common generic `ZipCode` interface.

**Update:** A ZIP code is five digits. A ZIP+4 code consists of the primary five-digit ZIP code plus a four-digit plus-4 (+4) code. You can create a ZIP+4 from a regular ZIP and get the primary ZIP from a ZIP+4. Thus, the interface which the two classes implement knows about the two classes, and they know about each other.

```
interface ZipCode
    boolean isPlusFour()
    ZipPlusFour plusFour(String code)
    Zip primary()
    boolean hasSamePrimary(ZipCode other)

class Zip implements ZipCode
    String code

class ZipPlusFour implements ZipCode
    Zip primary
    String plusFourCode
```

**Introducing Null Object Pattern**

To avoid duplicating code that checks for null values throughout the application, I would like to introduce the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). However, I'm afraid the only way to do so that supports the features above is to add three new classes instead of just one:

```
class NullZipCode implements ZipCode
class NullZip extends Zip
class NullZipPlusFour extends ZipPlusFour
```

Worse, since the last two extend concrete classes they will need to pass special values to their superclass that will pass validation but not block the possibility of using real values. For example, `NullZip` would call `super("00000")`.

Here are my main questions, though please don't hesitate to throw out any suggestions you have.

1. Is there a way to solve this with just one new class to cover all bases?
2. Is it worth extracting interfaces from `Zip` and `ZipPlusFour` so that `NullZip` won't extend the concrete `Zip` implementation (same for `ZipPlusFour`)?

   ```
   ZipCode
     Zip
       NullZip
       RealZip
   ```
3. Another option is to forego separate classes altogether and check for a special value in `Zip` and `ZipPlusFour` to signify a missing ZIP code.

   ```
   class Zip
       boolean isNone() {
           return code.equals("00000");
       }

       boolean hasSamePrimary(ZipCode other) {
           if (isNone() || other.isNone())
               return false;
           else
               return code.equals(other.primary().code);
       }
   ```

   At least the complicated checks are encapsulated in these classes which is the whole point of introducing the pattern. The downside is that this logic can be more fragile than inheritance. Is this a good trade-off?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your interface.  Why does the interface know about the concrete objects that implement it, and have functions that return both?  Who is using this that they'll be able to differentiate between the two classes - other developers?  This might be a place to use composition instead of inheritance.  Is there ever a scenario where you would want to allow a base zipcode and *not* allow a Zip+4?

Comment: @Bobson - `ZipPlusFour` is composed of a `Zip` (the *primary*) and a four-digit +4 code. You can get a ZIP+4 from a ZIP by adding a +4 code, and you can get the primary ZIP from a full ZIP+4. I'll explain this more in the question.

Comment: If you can always transform one into another, then why have them be separate in the first place?  Just have one class, and provide a `HasPlusFour()` function to differentiate them, and a `ToString()` which returns the appropriate string representation depending on whether the +4 is there or not.

Comment: @Bobson - I want clients to be able to declare via the parameter type that they accept or return a single form. A `Customer` has a `Zip` since we do not store the +4 if provided when parsing, but `Dealer` has a `ZipCode` because it may be either a ZIP or ZIP+4 code. `Phone`, on the other hand, accepts an optional extension using a single class as you describe.

Comment: @DavidHarkness where are you using `boolean isPlusFour()`? Can we see some example code?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca - Only in test code. The production code places constraints on which types it accepts (sometimes) but lets the behavior be decided by the implementation. Thus it never needs to ask a ZIP code which type it is. If we merged the classes as we did with `Phone`, it would be required to perform validation checks.

Comment: Clearly this question is simplified with a single-class "hierarchy" as we have with `Phone`. Assume for the sake of this question that going that route isn't practical.

Comment: @DavidHarkness You stated a `Customer` has a ZIP and `Dealer` has a ZIP+4, so to speak. Do you have another class, say `Address`, that has 'either' a ZIP or a ZIP+4?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca - Yes, as I said above, `Dealer` has a `ZipCode` to allow either a `Zip` or `ZipPlusFour`. Just take it as a given that the separate classes are required along with the interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is a preliminary answer:

> Assume for the sake of this question that going that route isn't
>   practical.

Assuming this is about some group of similar value objects.
Everything is meaningful in a context. So we need to determine what are the use cases for this object. Suppose we have the following use cases (I'm trying to guess how you could end up with the provided interfaces.):

1. We need to display a ZipCode on screen
2. We need to print ZipCode on envelopes
3. We also need to lookup some external service for demographic data using the 5-digit ZIP as a key.

Simplest thing that could work would then be something like:

```
interface ZipCode
    Zip primary() // for service lookup
    String getScreenRepresentation()
    String getPrintRepresentation()
    // you may one to use Visitor pattern 
    // if you have much more different formats
```

Now we may try to design a Null Object that could work for all these situations.
for ZIP and ZIP+4 their implementations are straight forward.
For `NullZipCode` we can have `getScreenRepresentation` to return `"No ZIP provided"` and 
`getPrintRepresentation` to return empty string. You definitely would not want "00000" or some other invalid value on the label. (Unless in the improbable case that US postal service requires people put it to designate unknown ZIP, but you get what I mean)

My criticism of the below code

```
interface ZipCode
    boolean isPlusFour()
    ZipPlusFour plusFour(String code)
    Zip primary()
    boolean hasSamePrimary(ZipCode other)

class Zip implements ZipCode
    String code

class ZipPlusFour implements ZipCode
    Zip primary
    String plusFourCode
```

`isPlusFour` is the back door where all the null checks sneak back in.

`plusFour(code)` does not belong in the interface. It is a factory method. One sign it does not belong there is `Zip` and `ZipPlusFour` should not be able to provide different versions.

`hasSamePrimary` is unnecessary. Value objects should provide their equality, comparison, hash, display string etc. by overriding equals, hashCode etc in Java, (or deriving Show, Eq in Haskell and so on). By value object semantics; `zipCode1.hasSamePrimary(zipCode2)` **should** be equivalent to `zipCode1.primary().equals(zipCode2.primary())`, it is not an overridable behavior (Closed for modification principle). If it is there for brevity, it can be placed in an abstract base class or as a static method in a Utility class (or extension method if you are using C#, etc.)

What you should do for `Dealer` class cannot be a simple interface, if it is to be a value object also.

```
class ZipOrZipPlusFour implements ZipCode
     //fields depend on what sort of persistence you use
     // factory methods:
     newNullZipCode()
     newZip(String code)
     newZipPlusFour(Zip primary, String ext)

class Dealer
    ZipOrZipPlusFour zipCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand why they have to be separate classes, but here's my take on it:

```
interface ZipCode
  boolean isPlusFour()
  boolean hasSamePrimary(ZipCode other)
  String code
  String display

interface ZipCodePlusFour extends ZipCode
  String plusFourCode
  override String display
  boolean hasSamePlusFour(ZipCodePlusFour other)

class ZipCode implements ZipCode
  // Nothing here that isn't in the interface
class ZipPlusFour extends ZipCode implements ZipCodePlusFour
  // Nothing here that isn't in the interface

class NullZip implements ZipCode
  // Null responses for everything
class NullZipPlusFour extends NullZip implements ZipCodePlusFour
  // Null responses for everything that NullZip doesn't already do.
```

Everything in your code should either require the `ZipCode` interface or the `ZipCodePlusFour` interface.  If the former, it can accept any of the four classes.  If the latter, it requires the plus four bit.  Since a plus four can always be downgraded to a pure zipcode, this set of inheritance will let you pass a +4 wherever you are looking for a `ZipCode`.

Also, by always requiring the interface, rather than the concrete type, you can trivially implement the null object pattern you asked about.

Comment: They are separate so I can specify that one parameter allows a +4 code while another does not. When both are acceptable, use the interface. Certainly I could use a single class and perform validation checks as you would with `nonNegativeLength`. However, compile-time checks are les prone to error than runtime validation.

Comment: @DavidHarkness - It's been a long time, but I think what I meant by "separate" is "not inheriting".  Having the +4 version inherit from the base one still allows you to have compile-time checking, but allows you to reuse some functionality.